# How to use "IN" predicate in Swift for doing ckQuery?

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, swift, nspredicate

I need to make a query from my application in swift. I'm using cloudKit so, I can't use the SQL language.

I wanna write an instruction that is similar to :

```
SELECT * 
FROM parola
WHERE IDParola IN ("1","4","5","10"); //And so on with numbers
```

I have read that in swift i have to use the NSPredicate, so I write:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "IDParola IN { "1", "2" }")
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Parola", predicate: predicate)
```

But This code give me the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Unexpected expression: IDParola IN {1, 2}'
*** First throw call stack..."

I read this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html , I tried without the ", I tried in all ways (I think), but it doesn't work. It only works if I write:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "IDParola = 1")
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Parola", predicate: predicate)
```

But with this code I retrive only one record... Who can help me? Thank you first!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "IDParola IN %@", [1, 2]) 
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Parola", predicate: predicate)
```

Comment: No worries, I’m glad to hear it solved your issue! :)